# How to save a dataframe result into a table in databricks?

Tags: python, nlp, databricks

I am trying to save a list of words that I have converted to a dataframe into a table in databricks so that I can view or refer to it later when my cluster restarts.

I have tried the below code but it keeps giving me an error or does run but I can't see the table in the database

```py
myWords_External=[['this', 'is', 'my', 'world'],['this', 'is', 'the', 'problem']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(myWords_External)
df1.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("temp.eehara_trial_table_9_5_19")
```

the last line gives me the following error

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Answer (score 22):

I think you have mixed up two different technologies in your code. The first part is pandas:

```py
myWords_External=[['this', 'is', 'my', 'world'],['this', 'is', 'the', 'problem']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(myWords_External)
```

and the second part is pyspark:

```py
df1.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("temp.eehara_trial_table_9_5_19")
```

I don't know what your use case is but assuming you want to work with pandas and you don't know how to connect to the underlying database it is the easiest way to just convert your pandas dataframe to a pyspark dataframe and save it as a table:

```py
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(df1)

spark_df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("temp.eehara_trial_table_9_5_19")

#you can create a new pandas dataframe witht the following command:
pd_df = spark.sql('select * from temp.eehara_trial_table_9_5_19').toPandas()
```

This is inefficient and it is better to use the pandas.[to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_sql) function, but you need to know the provided database and the connection credentials for that.